# JavaScript - (window.addEventListener)

Tags: javascript

all

In the if statement fragment "if (window.addEventListener)" what does
the window.addEventListener resolve to. I believe it is a boolean but when is it "true" and when is it "false". I have been researching for a week but to no avail.

I am learning JavaScript by doing self-study, so bear with me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 1):

Any `if` expression like that — that is, one without an explicit comparison — implicitly converts the expression value to a boolean. The rules in JavaScript are that anything other than `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, or `false` is considered `true`.

Thus, testing `window.addEventListener` like that is a way to check whether that property exists (is not `undefined`) on the `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

`window.addEventListener` in all modern browsers refers to a function. In JavaScript, any value can be coerced to boolean. The result is either `false` (for `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false` — the "falsy" values) or `true` (for all other values — the "truthy" values). So if `addEventListener` exists on `window` and has a truthy value (a function reference is truthy), the code branches into the body of the `if`. If not (obsolete versions of Internet Explorer didn't have it, they had the Microsoft precursor to it called `attachEvent`), looking up the property will result in `undefined`, which is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

Just for refer, javascript uses 'Falsy' values that is a value that translates to false when evaluated in a Boolean context.

Reference [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)